# Which stack does hardware interrupt use?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, interrupt

I don't quite understand the interrupt stack switch mechanism in `x86_64`. From Intel's developer's manual, when a hardware interrupt occurs, the current context will be stored on **interrupt stack** for later `iret` use. I have the following questions:

1. Is this stack `hardirq_stack` in Linux kernel? If it is, this stack is also used by `softirq`; so how does the stack keep consistency when an interrupt occurs during handling `softirq`? If it is not, which stack is used?
2. Only a part of the context is saved on the stack (e.g., RSP, CS, RIP), what about the other part (e.g., registers)?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the following: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/kernel-stacks, you have information on what Linux does for the different stacks.

> Like all other architectures, x86_64 has a kernel stack for every
> active thread.

This means that each process/thread has one kernel stack which is used to handle syscalls. The libstdc++/libc (standard C++/C implementations) use the syscall assembly instruction directly to make system calls. The entry point to the kernel is arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S. This assembly file will switch the stack of the user mode process to its kernel counterpart. This is during a syscall not during an external interrupt. This paragraph is just to clear misconceptions.

> In addition to the per thread stacks, there are specialized stacks
> associated with each CPU.  These stacks are only used while the kernel
> is in control on that CPU; when a CPU returns to user space the
> specialized stacks contain no useful data.  The main CPU stacks are:
>
> - Interrupt stack.  IRQ_STACK_SIZE
>
> Used for external hardware interrupts.  If this is the first external
> hardware interrupt (i.e. not a nested hardware interrupt) then the
> kernel switches from the current task to the interrupt stack.  Like
> the split thread and interrupt stacks on i386, this gives more room
> for kernel interrupt processing without having to increase the size
> of every per thread stack.
>
> The interrupt stack is also used when processing a softirq.
>
> Switching to the kernel interrupt stack is done by software based on a
> per CPU interrupt nest counter.

This means that each CPU has some specialized stacks which are used to handle some special events. The specialized stacks don't contain valid data when in user mode.

The kernel maintains a nest counter (interrupt of an interrupt). If the nest counter is 0, it will switch the user mode stack to the interrupt kernel stack. Otherwise, it will remain on the same stack.

> Is this stack hardirq_stack in Linux kernel? If it is, this stack is also used by softirq; so how does the stack keep consistency when an interrupt occurs during handling softirq? If it is not, which stack is used?

The stack used is the interrupt stack for both the hardirq (hardware irq) and softirq (software irq). The stack remains consistent because the irq handler pushes all registers that could be used by a nested interrupt and maintains a nest counter. The TSS is used for irq going from ring 3 to ring 0 to switch the stacks. This is necessary because the switch to kernel mode (ring 0) cannot be done by software. It must be done by hardware. The TSS is a mechanism which allows safe switch to kernel mode on interrupt.

> Only a part of the context is saved on the stack (e.g., RSP, CS, RIP), what about the other part (e.g., registers)?

The registers are also saved on the stack.

Comment: Actually, after reading some more, I think the TSS would not be necessary if the processor didn't blindly use it to switch the stacks on ring 3 to ring 0 transition. For some reason, the processor still does that on x86-64 so it must be set up but only for RSP0.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I want to make the following statement more clear. As you explained, the TSS mechanism is used for irq when CPL changes. So when the interrupt occurs in user mode, the stack is switched by TSS mechanism(hardware); when it occurs in kernel mode for the first time, the stack is switched by the kernel itself(software). And the stack pointers in these two situations are the same. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes I am quite sure this is correct. My answer is partially wrong as it says that the kernel will switch the user mode stack to the kernel interrupt stack. This is wrong. The kernel sets up the TSS to switch the stacks on ring3 to ring0 transition. Like you say, if a CPU is already in kernel mode than it switches the stacks in software depending on the nest counter.

Comment: For example, if the CPL is 0 on the CPU at the moment of an interrupt due to a syscall from user mode, the kernel will switch the stacks itself to the interrupt stack. If the CPU is in ring0 due to an interrupt than it won't switch the stack and it will nest the interrupts on the same stack.

Comment: However, in my exploring (Linux kernel 5.10), the TSS seems only to switch the stack from CPL3 to CPL0, and the actual interrupt stack switch is done by the kernel.